# Swapping Axes in Pandas

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, swap

What is the most efficient way to swap the axes of a Pandas Dataframe?

For example, how could df1 be converted to df2 below?

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   one  two
0    1    4
1    2    3
2    3    2
3    4    1

In [5]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({0 : [1,4], 1 : [2,3], 2 : [3,2], 3 : [4,1]}, index=['one','two'])

In [6]: df2
Out[6]: 
     0  1  2  3
one  1  2  3  4
two  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Take a look at [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

```
In [4]: df1.T
Out[4]: 
     0  1  2  3
one  1  2  3  4 
two  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: The link is not working. Working (as of Feb 2023) link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html