# How to invert the axis of a dataframe during its creation

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

By creating a df from the date of a json file, I'm getting the results with the axis inverted than I'd like to. E.g. for...

`df = pd.DataFrame(data['relevant_cohort'])`

I get...

```
---- X1 - X2
Y1 - 0,1 - 0,3
Y2 - 2.3 - 1.1
```

But I'd like to have Xs as rows and Ys as columns.

How could I invert columns x rows during the creation of the DF? Thx!

Comment: use `.transpose()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping Axes in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301546/swapping-axes-in-pandas)